# how to sort stock by quantity in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, stock, sort

In magento frontend i want to sort products by **maximum quantity first** to **lower number of stock** (Quantity sort in descending order)

Please advise which module to be made and where to save the files
i am using magento 2.3.0

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to attributes settings

> Store -> Attributes -> Products

Open attribute with the lable **"Quantity"**

Open tab: **"Storefront Properties"**

Set **"Used for Sorting in Product Listing"** to **"Yes"** and save it

Open category where you want your sorting.

> Catalog -> Categories

Open your category, now open **"Display settings"** tab and set **"Quantity"** in **"Default Product Listing Sort By"** dropdown

Now to add descending sorting, open tab **"Design"**
and add this xml code here

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setDefaultDirection">
              <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
            </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Refresh frontend category page and see if it is working. I personally implemented this it was working for me.

Hope you find your solution

Comment: Bother Jazak allah , Allah bless you my brother , Thank you so much !!!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 779110403205

Comment: Please check error detail in **var/report/779110403205** file

Comment: the page do not load and shows error. when i use sort by Quantity...There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 779110403205

Comment: in order to read detail of your error you need to open file in **var/report** directory, and file name would be **779110403205**

Comment: Allah bless you for helping me , i am so thankful that you are helping me ,   the report is long and pasting here exceeds the characters so please check this weblink  
   http://www.magshahindia.com/sort-by-quantity-error-report/?___store=admin

Comment: According to this, your sorting is applied 2 times in your code. Can you defined steps that you are taking for sorting?

Comment: http://www.magshahindia.com/merino-wool/merino-superbanu-silk-plaid.html  please check this link and when you choose sort by quantity it stops working and we have pasted your given in xml code ... <referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setDefaultDirection">
              <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
            </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: Remove xml temporarily, flush cache and try again, check if error appears or not. This will tell you if you are facing this issue due to xml

Comment: I have tested it on my website. I think you missed the part where you need to select **Default sort by** to **quantity**. Please recheck steps in answer

Comment: Asalamu alikum Dear brother Shoaib Bhai ...when i keep  "Display settings" tab and set "Quantity" in "Default Product Listing Sort By" dropdown , i get error Default Product Listing Sort by does not exist in Available Product Listing Sort By. please advise jazak allah , please advise

Comment: Recheck Quantity attribute settings, see if **Used for Sorting in Product Listing** is **Yes**. Then run indexing through shell, then assign Quantity in Default Product Listing

Comment: did everything but quantity do not sort of decending or ascending stock , its not working , thank you for your kind help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

shoaib bhai asalamu alikum
thank you so much i finally found the solution after one year

store > configuration > catalog > storefront > Use Flat Catalog Category (NO)
if the flat category will be yes then it wont let product be sorted by quantity.
i realized it when i updated the products and did not performed reindexing due to which it worked fine but once i reindexed sort by quantity starting acting as sort by position.

It is very important to keep Flat catalog category OFF.